# Chart.js Radar chart multiple datasets

Tags: mysql, charts, chart.js

I have a MySQL table, part of which looks like this[image: MySQL Database]

I am useing the following query to get the count how many times each aspect was selected from the database and converte it to JSON in order to use it for a Radar Chart.

```
SELECT Aspect,COUNT(Aspect) as AspectNumber from text_xml group by Aspect
```

The final JSON output looks like this

```
[  
   {  
      "Aspect":" Structure",
      "AspectNumber":"18"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "AspectNumber":"96"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"I am rather good at this",
      "AspectNumber":"55"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"I did\/saw this in the past",
      "AspectNumber":"95"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"I didn't realize I wasn't doing this",
      "AspectNumber":"75"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"I like this point",
      "AspectNumber":"263"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "AspectNumber":"190"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "AspectNumber":"81"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"Structure",
      "AspectNumber":"62"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"Visual adis",
      "AspectNumber":"17"
   },
   {  
      "Aspect":"Visual aids",
      "AspectNumber":"69"
   }
]
```

Then I produce a chart with the following code

```
$.ajax({
        // Get the data for the chart
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/radardata.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var numcomments = [];
            var users = [];

            // Get the different values into an array 
            for(var i in data) {
                numcomments.push(data[i].AspectNumber);
                users.push(data[i].Aspect);
            }

            // Load the data into the chart
            var chartdata1 = {
                labels: users,
                datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Selected",
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(178, 223, 219,0.2)",
                    borderColor: "#009688",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#004D40",
                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                    data: numcomments
                }
                ]
            };

            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#E0E0E0';
            Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color = "#9E9E9E";
            Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.zeroLineColor = "#9E9E9E";

            var ctx = $("#linechart");

            // Create the chart and its options
            var options = {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRadio: true,
                tooltips: {
                    enable: true,
                    mode: 'label',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data){
                            var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                            return datasetLabel + ': ' + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel) + ' Times';
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: false,
                },
                scale: {
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "#9E9E9E",
                    },
                    angleLines: {
                        color: '#9E9E9E'
                    },
                    reverse: false,
                    ticks: {
                        showLabelBackdrop: false,
                        min: 0,
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        stepSize: 30
                    },
                },
                scaleOverride: false,
                scaleSteps: 5,
                scaleStepWidth: 20,
                scaleStartValue: 100,
            };

            var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'radar',
                data: chartdata1, 
                options: options
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Which looks like this:[image: Radar Chart]

However, now I am trying to show how many times in each video, each aspect was selected, and plot it on the radar chart.

The query that I am using for this produces this JSON output

```
[  
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1: How to Give an Awesome (PowerPoint) Presentation ",
      "Aspect":"I am rather good at this",
      "Count":"17"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1: How to Give an Awesome (PowerPoint) Presentation ",
      "Aspect":"I did\/saw this in the past",
      "Count":"29"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1: How to Give an Awesome (PowerPoint) Presentation ",
      "Aspect":"I didn't realize I wasn't doing this",
      "Count":"8"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1: How to Give an Awesome (PowerPoint) Presentation ",
      "Aspect":"I like this point",
      "Count":"52"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1: How to Give an Awesome (PowerPoint) Presentation ",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"28"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?",
      "Aspect":"I am rather good at this",
      "Count":"8"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?",
      "Aspect":"I did\/saw this in the past",
      "Count":"25"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?",
      "Aspect":"I didn't realize I wasn't doing this",
      "Count":"29"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?",
      "Aspect":"I like this point",
      "Count":"84"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"27"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs",
      "Aspect":"I am rather good at this",
      "Count":"19"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs",
      "Aspect":"I did\/saw this in the past",
      "Count":"22"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs",
      "Aspect":"I didn't realize I wasn't doing this",
      "Count":"14"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs",
      "Aspect":"I like this point",
      "Count":"75"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"44"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence",
      "Aspect":"I am rather good at this",
      "Count":"11"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence",
      "Aspect":"I did\/saw this in the past",
      "Count":"19"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence",
      "Aspect":"I didn't realize I wasn't doing this",
      "Count":"24"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence",
      "Aspect":"I like this point",
      "Count":"52"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"22"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Abraham Heifets: How can we make better medicines? Computer tools for chemistry",
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "Count":"25"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Abraham Heifets: How can we make better medicines? Computer tools for chemistry",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"8"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Abraham Heifets: How can we make better medicines? Computer tools for chemistry",
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "Count":"14"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Abraham Heifets: How can we make better medicines? Computer tools for chemistry",
      "Aspect":"Structure",
      "Count":"24"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Abraham Heifets: How can we make better medicines? Computer tools for chemistry",
      "Aspect":"Visual aids",
      "Count":"11"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve",
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "Count":"2"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"2"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve",
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "Count":"4"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve",
      "Aspect":"Structure",
      "Count":"1"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve",
      "Aspect":"Visual aids",
      "Count":"2"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender ",
      "Aspect":" Structure",
      "Count":"18"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender ",
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "Count":"22"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender ",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"18"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender ",
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "Count":"14"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender ",
      "Aspect":"Visual aids",
      "Count":"44"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web",
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "Count":"20"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"25"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web",
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "Count":"36"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web",
      "Aspect":"Structure",
      "Count":"21"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web",
      "Aspect":"Visual adis",
      "Count":"17"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online \"filter bubbles\"",
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "Count":"8"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online \"filter bubbles\"",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"5"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online \"filter bubbles\"",
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "Count":"1"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online \"filter bubbles\"",
      "Aspect":"Structure",
      "Count":"2"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online \"filter bubbles\"",
      "Aspect":"Visual aids",
      "Count":"2"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Jasdeep Saggar: Hypoxia-activated pro-drugs: a novel approach for breast cancer treatment",
      "Aspect":"Delivery",
      "Count":"19"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Jasdeep Saggar: Hypoxia-activated pro-drugs: a novel approach for breast cancer treatment",
      "Aspect":"No Aspect Selected",
      "Count":"11"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Jasdeep Saggar: Hypoxia-activated pro-drugs: a novel approach for breast cancer treatment",
      "Aspect":"Speech",
      "Count":"12"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Jasdeep Saggar: Hypoxia-activated pro-drugs: a novel approach for breast cancer treatment",
      "Aspect":"Structure",
      "Count":"14"
   },
   {  
      "VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 4 - Jasdeep Saggar: Hypoxia-activated pro-drugs: a novel approach for breast cancer treatment",
      "Aspect":"Visual aids",
      "Count":"10"
   }
]
```

However, I am not shure how ti integrate that data in the radar chart.

What I hope of achieving is something like this. Each different color would be the data from the different video[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically push the data in the dataset for achieving the same in the js file.

Below is the Template for the same:

To Create the Dataset and the Labels :

```
var color = ["rgba(241,28,39,1)", //red
            "rgba(28,145,241,1)",//blue
            "rgba(231,221,28,1)", //yellow
            "rgba(38,231,28,1)", //green
            "rgba(28,231,221,1)", //cyan
            "rgba(231,228,211,1)", //pink
            "rgba(3,1,3,1)", // black
            "rgba(236,176,179,1)", //light pink
            "rgba(239,107,51,1)", //orange
            "rgba(157,51,239,1)", //violet
            "rgba(16,82,248,1)", //royalblue
            "rgba(241,28,39,1)"];

    ChartData = {}; 
    ChartData.labels = []; 
    ChartData.datasets = []; 
    for (index = 0; index <Number_of_Video_Names; index++) {
            temp = [];
        ChartData.datasets.push({});
        dataset = ChartData.datasets[index]
        dataset.backgroundColor = color[index],
        dataset.borderColor = color[index],
        dataset.label =  [label1,label2,label3]; //labels
        dataset.data = []; //data on Y-Axis
        ChartData.datasets[index].data = [10,20,30,40,50]; //data
    }
```

To Create the Graph

```
var RadarGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: Chartdata, 
    });
```

This Should work for you .